# Error: Table social_profiles for model SocialProfile was not found in datasource default

Tags: facebook, cakephp, model, hybridauth, social-media

I am trying to get social logins to work using hybridauth

my app/Model/SocialProfile.php looks like

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class SocialProfile extends AppModel {
        public $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

my app/Model/User.php looks like

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'SocialProfile' => array(
            'className' => 'SocialProfile',
        )
    );
....
```

I am getting this error:
Error: Table social_profiles for model SocialProfile was not found in datasource default.

Thank you for you assitance

Comment: Do you have table name Exactly like -> social_profiles ?

Answer (score 0):

> If social_profiles table is present in your database, not require to
>   define in model. But in your case its not working. so you need to
>   alternative process in **CakePHP**.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class SocialProfile  extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'social_profile '; 
    // This model uses a database      table 'social_profile'
    public $name = 'SocialProfile ';  
   // If you do not specify it in your model file it will be set to the 
   // class name by constructor.
}
```

I hope the above model will be work for you perfectly. I have found your solution from read this [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html)

Comment: Thanks so much. I eventually found the proper script to create the table in the full download @ http://miftyisbored.com/wp-tutorials/cakephp-2_3-social-auth.zip

Comment: Great..enjoy yourself.